# At take-off, what is the deflection angle of the rudder for the legacy Hornet?

Tags: takeoff, pilot-technique, rudder, fa-18

At take-off, what is the deflection angle of the (legacy) [F/A-18 Hornet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_F/A-18_Hornet)'s rudders?

Comment: Please don't create new tags, when there are appropriate existing tags already.

Comment: Taking off from a carrier or from an airfield?

Comment: It's the same .Canada's F18 don't fly from the carrier and rudders is used in the same way.

Comment: @GeorgeGeo Please include such information in the question itself.  It is relevant.